# How to set up a double integral with $x,y$ and $z$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Use a double integral to find the volume of the solid bounded by graphs of the equations given by: $z=xy^3, Z>0,\; X>0,\; 5X<Y<5$
How would you set up this integral? please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how

> $$ \int_{0}^{1}\int_{5x}^{5} xy^3 dydx.$$

You should plot the graph in xy-plane to see what's happening.

**Note:** More generally, if the region bounded by two surfaces, namely from below by $z_1=f_1(x,y) $ and above by $z_2=f_2(x,y)$, then the volume of the region is given by

> $$ \int\int_{A} (z_2-z_1) dA .$$

Comment: Thanks! I still have one question how did you know X was from 0 to 1?

Comment: @jainsmit: Solve the equations $y=5x$ and $y=5$ and find the intersection point. As I said plot the region. Plot the function $y=5x$ and the function $y=5$ and you will see the region.

Comment: Ok makes sense. what did you do to the z?
sorry a lot of questions just want to understand it.

Comment: If you want to find the volume using the double integral, then we consider $$ \int\int zdA= \int\int f(x,y)dydx .$$

Comment: ohh alright makes sense! Thanks

Comment: @jainsmit: You are welcome.